# Как правильно настроить роутинг в своём проекте?

Tags: php, mvc

Я пишу свой небольшой учебный проект с нуля, не используя фреймворк. К сожалению, не смог найти какой то однозначной информации, по поводу того как правильно настроить роутинг.

В принципе, при ожидаемом поведении - всё работает.
Но если, например, обратится к файлу index.php напрямую - возникнет ошибка(ровно как и к любому другому php фалу). Если обратится к какой-либо папке - то доступ в неё тоже будет, а значит уже возможно будет посмотреть структуру проекта.
Даже при написании просто случайных символов в адресую строку - роутер попытается выполнить соответствующий метод.

Хотелось бы избавится от этих недочётов, что бы при обращении к несуществующим или не указанным в маршрутах файлам папкам перебрасывало, например, на главную страничку.

Ниже прикладываю содержимое роутера, маршрутов и .htaccess.

routes.php:

```
return array(
    'ajax/delFile/([0-9]+)' => 'ajax/delFile/$1',
    'ajax/delMessage/([0-9]+)' => 'ajax/delMessage/$1',
    'ajax/addPost/([0-9]+)' => 'ajax/addPost/$1',
    'ajax/addPost' => 'ajax/addPost',
    'editMessage/([0-9]+)' => 'message/editMessage/$1',
    'message/search' => 'message/searchMessage',
    'logout' => 'logout/logout',
    'ajax/register' => 'ajax/registerUser',
    'ajax/login' => 'ajax/loginUser',
    'sign-up' => 'signup/show',
    'message/([0-9]+)' => 'message/show/$1',
    '' => 'index/showAllMessages',
);
```

Router:

```
class Router
{
    private  $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $routesPath = __DIR__ . '/../../App/Config/routes.php';
        $this->routes = require_once ($routesPath);
    }

    /**
     * Получаем строку запроса
     *
     * @return bool|string Строка запроса, либо false если строка запроса отсутствует
     */
    private function getURI()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            return trim(str_replace('mvcguestbook', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '/');
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function run()
    {
        $uri = $this->getURI();

        //Проверяем наличие запроса в routes.php
        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {

            //Ищем в URI совпадение с регулярным выражением uriPattern
            if(preg_match("~$uriPattern~i", $uri)) {

                //Формируем из URI внутренний маршрут
                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~i", $path, $uri);

                //Определяем контроллер, экшн и параметры
                $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                $controllerName = 'App\\Controllers\\' . ucfirst(array_shift($segments) . 'Controller');
                $actionName = 'action'. ucfirst(array_shift($segments));

                $controllerObject = new $controllerName;
                $result = $controllerObject->$actionName($segments);
                if ($result != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mvcguestbook
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: Если вопрос про роутинг, то это одно. Если о том, как защиться от просмотра каталогов и несанкционированного доступа к php-файлам, то другое. Вы определитесь точнее.

Comment: @MAX, ну в общем суть вопроса то я описал достаточно подробно. Если смущает заголовок вопроса - предложите правку, и я её приму.

Comment: Какая ошибка? Визуально, ошибка у вас в `public function run()` - есть ситуации где пустота, такого не должно быть. Все остальное (доступ к папкам, файлам) - это все крутите в сторону `.htaccess`. Могу подтолкнуть ваши записи `!-f` и `!-d` - означают файлы и директории.

Comment: @Manitikyl , основная ошибка в том, что если я вбиваю в адресную строку  случайные символы, то в роутере срабатывает последняя регулярка из списка роутов (там где пустота). На сколько я понимаю, результат выполнения функции preg_match('', $url) всегда будет '1' для любого URL.

Я таким образом пытался реализовать следующую логику - "если не найдено совпадений в роутах " - грузи главную страницу со всеми сообщениями. Но где то срабатывает ошибка, и роутер пытается загрузить не существующий метод несуществующего класса. Вот только я не могу разобраться почему :(

Comment: Ну а конкретнее? какие роуты пытается загрузить, что-то хоть есть?

Comment: Также советую изменить регулярку: `~$uriPattern~i` на такую, типа: `~^$uriPattern$~i` - работать не будет. крч в начале и конце добавить `^` и `$`  соответственно. Чтобы указать начало и конец строки, потому что ваша конструкция работает не совсем четко.

Comment: @Manitikyl , задампил, вроде стало понятнее.
При вводе  в бразуер строки не прописанной в роутах, в роутере срабатывает последняя строка `'' => 'index/showAllMessages'`.  Где `$uriPattern` это пустое значение. Соответственно `preg_match("~$uriPattern~i", $uri)` будет `true` для любого `$uri`. А далее, для получения `$internalRoute`  я делаю `preg_replace("~$uriPattern~i", $path, $uri)` где `$path` это строка `index/showAllMessages`. При вводе в браузер `asdf` я получаю строку `index/showAllMessagesa/index/showAllMessagess/index/showAllMessagesd/index/showAllMessagesf`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79767/discussion-between-roman-andreev-and-manitikyl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приходим к выводу, для других может быть полезно:

1) удалить последний, пустой роутер, и обрабатывать его отдельно через `}else{...}` - если тело цикла не было выполнено.

2) например пустой контроллер у вас сейчас = `''`, переделать его в `'(.*)'`, а саму регулярку переделать в : `"~^$uriPattern$~i"`

**P.S.**

Обычно, у фреймов существует такое понятие как системные роуты, обычно они задаются в одном месте где и остальные (и их стоит сразу отделять от кастомных).

**default_controller** (*обычно выводится на пустую уришку, для главной*)

**404** (*если роут не был найден*)

**error** (*если были ошибки в скриптах, то вызывают этот контроллер, обычно для этого используют [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php), [set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php), [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php)*)

Вот пример 3-ех системных роутов, их может быть больше.